# Are the IEEE 802.3 Clause 40 1000BASE-T MDI-X signal names wrong?

Tags: ethernet

IEEE 802.3 Clause 40 specifies the 1000BASE-T MDI and MDI-X connector pin-outs as:

[image]

Below, in §40.8.2, it says

> For a PHY that does not implement the crossover function, **the MDI labels in the middle column** of Table 40–12 **refer to its own internal circuits**. For PHYs that do implement the internal crossover, **the MDI labels in the last column** of Table 40–12 **refer to the internal circuits of the *remote* PHY** of the link segment.

Assuming a link composed of one MDI PHY and one MDI-X PHY connected with a straight-through cable, this paragraph leads to a contradiction: if the labels in the middle and last columns both refer to the PHY that does not implement the crossover function (*i.e.*, the MDI PHY), then contact 1 is being assigned two labels: BI_DA+ *and* BI_DB+.

Is it true that the signal called BI_DA on one PHY is called BI_DB on the partner PHY? If it is, then §40.8.2 (quoted above) is wrong: the MDI labels in the last column refer to the PHY's own internal circuits, *not* the remote PHY's circuits.

Comment: Please don't change your question to something entirely different. Instead, post another question to ask something else.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely different — it's still seeking an explanation of Table 40–12. Sorry for the churn — I'm so confused I'm not sure what question to ask.

Comment: Then your question wasn't clear before (totally valid though). In any case, please revert to the previous question and ask another one.

Comment: Here's the new question: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84858/why-does-1000base-t-require-a-crossover-function

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, when you look at each pin function. However, the pairs are called BI_Dx - *bidirectional* data, not *Receive* or *Transmit* like with 10BASE-T or 100BASE-TX.

Think of BI_Dx as a named pair. The name doesn't reflect its (PMA) function, but its position in the connector.

If you picture BI_DA as consisting of a R_D1 subchannel for receive and a T_D2 subchannel for transmit, likewise BI_DB as R_D2 & T_D1 (mirroring BI_DA) and so on, it all works out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I'm following. What do you mean by R_D1 for receive and T_D2 for transmit?